# Does the iBGP belong IGP?

Tags: bgp, igp

[image]

We know the iBGP in the AS can transmit the BGP data, it running in the AS, is it belong IGP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the concepts of stub and transit (core) autonomous systems were introduced in EGP, that pioneering protocol also introduced the concepts of interior and exterior neighbors. That is, if an EGP process peers with a neighbor in the same AS, the neighbor is interior; if the neighbor is in a different AS, the neighbor is exterior.

BGP uses the same concept: If a BGP session is established between two neighbors in different autonomous systems, the session is external BGP (EBGP), and if the session is established between two neighbors in the same AS, the session is internal BGP (IBGP). Example:

[image]

IGP means Interior Routing Protocol, and EGP – Exterior Routing Protocol.

OSPF, IS-IS, RIP and EIGRP are IGP Protocols. BGP is the only available EGP Protocol.

The original intent of protocol designers was to use IGP within the boundaries of a network and EGP outside of these boundaries.

Source: https://www.networkcomputing.com/data-centers/bgp-basics-internal-and-external-bgp/1830126875

Comment: those concept I know, the iBGP is running in a AS, but its load-carrying is exterior routes. so you mean the iBGP also is BGP?

Comment: Yes. iBGP is a peering between routers in **same** AS. eBGP - between **different** AS numbers. But it's still the same BGP protocol.

Comment: @three-blocks Yes exactly what Andrey wrote.